# variable and selector with JQuery

Tags: jquery

Can you explain the difference

**between this:**

```
$(document).on("change", "#domaine_uid", function() {
    $("#site_uid").empty();
});
```

**and this:**

```
const site_uid = $("#site_uid");
$(document).on("change", "#domaine_uid", function() {
    site_uid.empty();
});
```

Why does the second code does not work?

Answer (score 2):

The first one evaluates the `$("#site_uid")` in the click handler, so it is applied to any matching element found *when the click handler executes*.

The second one evaluates the `$("#site_uid")` once, and only once, right away.  So it is applied to any matching element found *when the page loads*.

Presumably the target element is added *after* the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

The second code does not work because you're saving `$("#site_uid")` inside a `const` (constant). `const` cannot be edited after declaration.

https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Use `let` or `var`.